# Error in reading text from textarea in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a webpage there is a textarea (id="text") and also a button (id="dlButton3").

What I have to do is to enter the text into the textarea. And when I press the button, then the following will be happened:

1. Text in the text area will be loaded into the function,
2. The text will be spitted with delimiters ""
3. There is a for loop to compare all the lengths of the strings, and
4. Print the longest one value

The problem is, with the following code, I can take the string from the text area but dun know why I cannot split the string, and it returns the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: targetString is not defined"

The code is as followed

```
function findlongestword(){
            var testing = document.getElementById('text').value;
            console.log(testing);
            var strText = testing.split(" ");
            var length = 0;
            for (var i=0; i < strText.length; i++) {
                if (length < strText[i].length) {
                    length = strText[i].length;
                    targetString = strText[i]
                }
            }
            console.log (targetString);
        }
        window.onload = function(){
            findlongestword();  
            document.getElementById("dlButton3").onclick = findlongestword;
        }
```

What can be the error?
Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: it actually happens because targetString is in fact not defined! It really can't get simpler than that. just add `var targetString` at the beginning of your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more about **block scope** targetString only exists within the loop

```
function findlongestword() {
  var testing = document.getElementById('text').value;
  var strText = testing.split(" ");
  var length = 0;
  var targetString = '';
  for (var i=0; i < strText.length; i++) {
    if (length < strText[i].length) {
      length = strText[i].length;
      targetString = strText[i]
    }
  }
  console.log (targetString);
}
window.onload = function() {
  findlongestword();
  document.getElementById("dlButton3").onclick = findlongestword;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Uncaught ReferenceError: targetString is not defined"
You did not declare targetString before using it within your loop. Therefore javascript did not know where to find or 'Refer' to it after the loop ended.

By adding var targetString  = ""; before the loop begins the problem will be solved.

```
function findlongestword(){
 var testing = document.getElementById('text').value;
            console.log(testing);
            var strText = testing.split(" ");
             //ADD HERE                
             var targetString = "";
            var length = 0;

            for (var i=0; i < strText.length; i++) {
                if (length < strText[i].length) {
                    length = strText[i].length;
                    targetString = strText[i]
                }
            }
            console.log (targetString);
        }
        window.onload = function(){
            findlongestword();  
            document.getElementById("dlButton3").onclick = findlongestword;
        }
```